# Retornar array de propriedades no laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Criei uma função no controller que me retorna os usuários onde a condição usuario_anjo for igual a 1.

Atualmente está retornando no json todos os dados desse usuário.

Como eu posso fazer pra retornar apenas os emails do usuário?

Tentei algo como:

```
public function avisarAnjos(Request $request){
    $usuariosAnjos = User::where('usuario_anjo', '1')->get();
    return response()->json($usuariosAnjos.email);
}
```

e:

```
public function avisarAnjos(Request $request){
    $usuariosAnjos = User::where('usuario_anjo', '1')->get();
    return response()->json($usuariosAnjos->email);
}
```

e

```
public function avisarAnjos(Request $request){
    $usuariosAnjos = User::where('usuario_anjo', '1')->get();
    return response()->json($usuariosAnjos['email']);
}
```

Comment: a resposta de ajudou a solucionar o seu problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para retornar apenas um campo utilize o método [select](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#selects) (ou  até [selectRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions)`) e traga apenas o(s) campo(s) no retorno do [builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries), ***exemplo***:

```
public function avisarAnjos(Request $request)
{
    $usuariosAnjos = User::where('usuario_anjo', '1')->select('email')->get();
    return response()->json($usuariosAnjos);
}
```

esse exemplo vai gerar uma [sql](/questions/tagged/sql): `SELECT email FROM users WHERE usuario_anjo = ?`, e o resultado somente a lista de e-mails conforme *filtro*.

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries)
- [Database: Query Builder - Selects](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#selects)
- [Database: Query Builder - Raw Expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function avisarAnjos(Request $request)
{
    $usuariosAnjos = User::where(['usuario_anjo'=>'1'])->get(['email']);
    return response()->json($usuariosAnjos);
}
```